Solving for P-Value from (1 - $\alpha$ CI) and vice versa
My understanding is that CI interval and P-value are interchangeable (even though CI has more information embedded within). I tried converting a hypothetical 95% CI to a P-Value and I'm not very sure the result is correct. Here is my working:
Suppose we have the following hypothesis:
$ H_0 : \mu = 2$ vs $H_1 : \mu \neq 2$
I assumed hypothetically that the 95% CI for $\mu$ is (1.5, 4.0), then I was interested in knowing what the P-Value would be if I calculated it by hand.
What I did was to get the population mean from the CI which is 2.75 (assuming symmetry).
$\frac{1.5 + 4.0}{2}=2.75$
Then I got a margin of error of 1.25 and a standard error of 0.6378
Margin of error = 4 - 2.75 = 2.75 - 1.5 = 1.25
$ SE = \frac{1.25}{1.96}= 0.6378$
I used 1.96 as the Z Score since it's two tailed.
Then I calculated the Z for the observed mean of 2:
$Z= \frac{2.75 - 2}{0.6378}= 1.176$
I then estimated the Probability of get a Zscore as extreme as 1.176 or more and multiply by 2 since it's two tailed and got 0.24.
Are my steps right?
